# Check assembly in GAC using MSBuild

Tags: msbuildextensionpack

I have some custom assemblies installed in GAC but when I try to check the existence of these using MSBuild task, it shows False. But, it does show the existence of framework assemblies. 
Here is my task:

```
<Target Name="CheckGAC">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Gac TaskAction="CheckExists" AssemblyName=Service.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=ed9f5fb552f617d7">
        <Output PropertyName="AssemblyExists" TaskParameter="Exists"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Gac>
    <Message Text="Exists: $(AssemblyExists)"/>
</Target>
```

Is there any reason it doesn't work with user assemblies in GAC ? or any other way to check if my assembly exists in GAC using MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually more than one GAC.  It could be that the Gac Task is looking in the .net 4.0 GAC and not the .net 2.0 one (or vice versa).